# Расчет RECT занимаемый текстом

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d

Использую библиотеку `dwrite` для рендера текста в `Direct2D`.
Текст хорошо рисуется, проблем никаких нет.

Можно ли как-то подсчитать заранее, до отрисовки текста реальный размер `D2D1::RectF` который он будет занимать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть метод [IDWriteTextLayout::GetMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316785(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Огромное спасибо =) Жаль только приходится каждый раз при изменении исходного текста делать перерасчеты.